# Convert fraction to continued fraction

Tags: python, fractions, continued-fractions

How would I convert a fraction to a continued fraction in Python? I tried looking around and found people using the Fraction module to do things similar to my problem, but I did not manage to modify them. An example with an image I found:

[image: example]

So if the input is `181 101`, then the output should be `1 1 3 1 4 4`. Thanks ahead!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: https://github.com/morris821028/UVa/blob/master/volume008/834%20-%20Continued%20Fractions.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's start with some mathematics. The rationale behind that is simple. For the fraction n/d, the euclidian division is n = d * q + r with r < d

We simply have n/d = (d * q + r) / d = q + r/d with r < d

Now we iterate with 1/(r/d) = d/r to get your *continued fraction*

It will lead to a finished sequence of q, because the denominator of the sequence of fractions constitute a stricly decreasing integer sequence which will reach 0 in at most d operations.

A possible Python implementation could be:

```
def cf(n, d):
    """Return the terms of the continued fraction when n is the numerator
and d the divisor as a list"""
    if d == 0: return []         # Ok it is finished
    q = n//d                     # compute the integer quotient
    r = n - q*d                  # the rest
    return [q] + cf(d, r)        # and recurse...
```

We get as expected:

```
>>> cf(181, 101)
[1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Is there a way to introduce a constraint through which we can say that the length of continued fraction should be at least > `k`?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Serge's answer, we can write an iterative version (Python3):

```
def cf(n, d):
    res = []
    q, r = divmod(n, d)
    while r != 0:
        res = res + [q]
        prev_r = r
        q, r = divmod(d, r)
        d = prev_r
    return res + [q]
```